# Fluid jQuery Slider similar to Xbox dashboard?

Tags: jquery, slider, fluid-layout, xbox

I'm searching for a full width/fluid jQuery slider script that is similar in behavior to the xbox 360 dashboard. When you're on a menu item on the dashboard, you can slightly see the next item or previous item on the sides of the screen. I'd like to find a script like that, where there's a smooth sliding effect to the next/previous items, and you can slightly see the next/previous items at the edge of your screen.

I know I've seen this idea out there on websites but I can't seem to find a script for it. Thanks for any tips!